# Apt package installer script sources

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm not looking for the source code for a particular program.

I'm looking for the source code of APT's configuration of a particular program.

When trying to search for this on the web, I get way too many hits about maintaining my system, how to get a package's sources, or how to configure my package manager.
None of these are things I want.
So I'm here.

I want the source repository of the `.deb` file that is used to install programs.
Unless I'm misunderstanding, Ubuntu maintains these installer files, probably with input from specific packages.

---

### Specific example

I'm trying to install and setup VirtualBox.
The package that is installed when I run `sudo apt install virtualbox` doesn't do 100% of what I expect it to do. Specifically, I think some of the "official" init scripts, notably `vboxautostart-service.sh`, are not being installed and I'm trying to get to the bottom of it.

I have no problem getting the sources of VirtualBox.
I can see `vboxautostart-service.sh` in the official sources under a "linux" folder.

I see that Apt gets the package from http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu (or similar).

Where can I see which steps Ubuntu's package maintainers have decided are needed to install and setup VirtualBox?

Following up, if I think I've found a bug, where can I go to discuss this with the people that can do something about it? I haven't found a git repo, for instance.

Comment: `apt source virtualbox`  will grab the source for the package `virtualbox`.  (for your release, you didn't specify, but it'll likely not be the latest unless you're using *hirsute* currently)

Comment: For bugs, if it's in a Ubuntu package, i'd file first with Ubuntu (`ubuntu-bug <package>` or see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)   If you believe it's an upstream issue, once confirmed (I usually confirm on another OS, myself I tend to use opensuse tumbleweed after my *hirsute* system; i test on debian *testing* of course & often fedora too; which depends on packages as they're some vary package-wise), then file it upstream; launchpad will provide clues where upstream is, and you can link the reports.

Comment: @guiverc While I could simply "report the bug", I'd rather take a look at the *package* source code before reporting the bug, because I can and because I'd be surprised if I cannot figure out the issue from looking at the *package* source. This doesn't have much to do with the *program*'s sources, which I have no trouble getting.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Debian has package sources at https://salsa.debian.org.

https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2017/12/msg00003.html

Virtualbox's package sources are here: https://salsa.debian.org/pkg-virtualbox-team/virtualbox

Answer (score 1):

To complete your research.

Currently both Debian and Ubuntu do [not](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=buster&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=vboxautostart-service.sh) [ship](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=vboxautostart-service.sh) `vboxautostart-service.sh` script. Bugs were reported:

- 7 years ago for Debian as [bug 748691](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=748691).
- today for Ubuntu as [bug 1912861](https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1912861).

As a temporary (?) workaround you can simply switch to [Oracle's packages](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads), as they have `vboxautostart-service.sh` in place.

Comment: [1912861](https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1912861) is mine ;)